# How to set more than one value for a same key?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, crossrider

I am using [Crossrider API](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api) to develop a browser extension.

I want to add multiple values for same key in [Crossrider local database](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db),

The method that crossrider supports is [appAPI.db.set](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-set)

```
appAPI.db.set(key, value, [expires])
```

But I want to save many values like:

```
appAPI.db.set('a.html',5,10,300)
```

It takes one value as a parameter, how to store many values for the same key?

Comment: I would create an array for the value of my key

Comment: The question is reasonable and has nothing vague or ambiguous. I'm wondering why it was closed !

Answer (score 2):

```
appAPI.db.set( 'a.html', [5,10,30], [expires] )
```

then to retrieve it:

```
var myValues = appAPI.db.get('a.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Arno2501, you can use [appAPI.db.set](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-set) and [appAPI.db.get](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-get) to work with the extension's local database.
The [appAPI.db](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db) API enables you to save your data in your preferred format. So you can either use the previously described array data, or save the values as a string, or object depending on your requirements. Additionally, you can specify how long you want the data to persist in your local database.

For example:

```
appAPI.db.set('key', ['a.html',5,10,300]); // Save data as an array
appAPI.db.set('key', ['a.html',5,10,300].join('&')); // OR as a string
appAPI.db.set('key', {'url':'a.html', 'values': [5,10,300]); // OR as an object

var keyValue = appAPI.db.get('key'); // keyValue contains the array, string, or object saved
```